# Printing content inside a scroller in Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, printing, flex4, air, adobe

I am currently working on an Adobe AIR application that shows the user some graphical data. As this data is more in height to fit the screen height, I've placed it inside a scroller.

Now I want to take a print of this visual data, mostly some charts and lists but I only see a single page containing only the part of the screen that is currently visible to the user. I want to have the entire content inside the scroller to appear on the page.

I tried using both PrintJob and FlexPrintJob but couldn't find a way around. Can anyone please help me by providing an insight, some source code will be greatly appreciated.

Looking forward to your replies,

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is apparently a known bug with the Flex printing library and Scroller controls.  You can read about my discussions on this here:
http://forums.adobe.com/message/3626759

As a workaround, I did the following:

```
var printer:FlexPrintJob = new FlexPrintJob();

// Display the print dialog to the user.  If they choose a printer
// and click "print", this method will return true, and we will
// spool the job to the printer they selected. If they hit cancel,
// this method will return false, and we will not attempt to send
// anything to the printer.
if(printer.start()){
     // Add some padding before spooling the object to the printer.
     // This will give it a reasonable margin on the printout.
     itemsToPrintContainer.paddingBottom = 100;
     itemsToPrintContainer.paddingTop = 100;
     itemsToPrintContainer.paddingLeft = 100;
     itemsToPrintContainer.paddingRight = 100;


     this.removeElement(itemsToPrintContainer);
     FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.addElement(itemsToPrintContainer);
     printer.addObject(itemsToPrintContainer);
     printer.send();
     FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.removeElement(itemsToPrintContainer);
     this.addElement(itemsToPrintContainer);

     // Reset the margins to 0 for display on the screen.
     itemsToPrintContainer.paddingBottom = 0;
     itemsToPrintContainer.paddingTop = 0;
     itemsToPrintContainer.paddingLeft = 0;
     itemsToPrintContainer.paddingRight = 0; 
}
```

That I'm doing is moving the object I want to print outside of the scroller, printing it, and then moving it back inside the scroller, so the user is unaware of any change.  The user might see a brief flash on the screen while things are re-arranged, but for my case that was acceptable.

Also, the padding was an attempt to add a margin to my printed output.  It will not work quite right if you have multiple pages.  You may not want to add padding in your particular case.

-Josh

Comment: Why was this not marked as the answer?  This is a solid workaround.

Comment: Good idea - this should be marked as the correct answer. In my case (generating alivepdf) there was no need of putting container to the topLevelApplciation.